# Remove space above the Pivot Item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have passed empty data context to the pivot header template. It having a space above the pivot item. How too get rid of the space

Below is my xaml code

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <ViewModels:ArticleViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTest">
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-25 0 -25 0">
                <Image x:Name="ArticleImage" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"></Image>
                <Grid>
                    <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="65" Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeadLine" Text="{Binding HeadLine}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                           Margin="10 0 0 5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                           FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                           Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo"
                                           FontWeight="Bold" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>                
            <AppBarButton x:Uid="Share">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/Share.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Favorite"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Comment"></AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Image Source="Assets/Maalaimalar_logo.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 5 0 0"></Image>
        </Grid>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" 
                             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTest}" 
                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">
            </Pivot>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Below is the xaml.cs part

```
 Feed data = new Feed();
        public ArticleDescriptionPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            data = e.Parameter as Feed;
            List<Article> feedList = new List<Article>();
            feedList = data.Articles;
            var viewModel = pivot.DataContext as ArticleViewModel;
            viewModel.BindListToView(feedList);
        }
```

Below is the ArticleViewModel

```
 public class ArticleViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<Article> articlesList = new ObservableCollection<Article>();

        public ArticleViewModel()
        {

        }

        public void BindListToView(List<Article> articleList)
        {
            Articles = new ObservableCollection<Article>(articleList);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Article> Articles
        {
            get { return this.articlesList; }
            set
            {
                Set<ObservableCollection<Article>>(ref this.articlesList, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the Article Class

```
public class Article
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string Title { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string HeadLine { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string Abstract { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string ArticleDetail { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public string ArticleId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public Article()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        /// <param name="headline"></param>
        /// <param name="imageURL"></param>
        /// <param name="articleAbstract"></param>
        /// <param name="articleDetail"></param>
        public Article(string title, string headline, string imageURL, string articleAbstract, string articleDetail, string articleId)
        {
            Title = title;
            HeadLine = headline;
            ImageURL = imageURL;
            Abstract = articleAbstract;
            ArticleDetail = articleDetail;
            ArticleId = articleId;
        }
    }
```

Below is the image which i am getting

[image]

Please guide me to get rid of the space above the pivot item. It looks more space above the pivot item and look awkward

Comment: Please provide a screen shot of what you are seeing.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please look into this

Comment: Why isn't  the image in the Pivot showing the word `Test` in the screenshot ..what happened to it?

Comment: What happens when you just put a rectangle (with a different color to make it stand out) in the place of the pivot control; does it have the same spacing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to do:

1. Remove the `Grid` around the image `Maalaimalar_logo.png` it is superfluous and not needed. That may adding space.
2. Either use a `StackPanel` or use a `Grid` to hold the template items. Using both is not helping. Change the template to:

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
       <Grid>
           <TextBlock Text="Test"></TextBlock>
           <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" ></Image>
           <Grid>
               <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="65" Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">
               </Border>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeadLine}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5 0 0 15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" />
           </Grid>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response OmegaMan. Its not working can u give some other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Set verticalAlignment to top or set row height to auto

Comment: Hi jrb thank you for your response. I tried your suggestions but it doesn't work. Can you give some other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I guess the space is caused by the header, try removing the header template of the pivot. That should do,if not,provide more info about the layout you are trying to achieve using the pivot.

Comment: Hi Chirag thanks for the response. Ya the space is caused by the header.I tried to remove the header but i cannot remove the header. The object is binding like Models.ViewModelslike that

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative value as margin to remove that blank space. Simply try

```
<Pivot Margin="0, -25, 0, 0">
```

Replace 25 with your desired value.